# How to add an element to arrayList when calling the method at the same time?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am doing a recursive program and I want to call a method 2 times in a row, which looks like this:

```
print(ArrayList<Integer> current + arr[0], Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length) );
print(ArrayList<Integer> current, Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length));
```

But it is impossible to add a value to the ArrayList like that. However, I can't use current.add() outside either, because it will mess up my second call.
So is there a way to add a value to the arrayList while calling the method, or do I have to think of another way to write my code?

Comment: Can't you add and then remove? Or create a new list with the additional element? Some context would be nice.

Comment: *why* would you even want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may overload your print method like the following:

```
public void print(ArrayList<Integer> current, int i, int[] arr ) {
    //print whatever you want
    //then add using current.add(i)
    current.add(i)
}
```

then call your overloaded `print()` method in the first time like this:

```
print(current, arr[0], arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with following code

```
print(new ArrayList<Integer>(current) {{ add(arr[0]); }},
      Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length) );
```